# php mysqli update with fetched

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to update a mysql database with data I fetched. (btw I need to do this for specific individual items, but that's not the problem.) When it comes to creating separate statements for fetching or updating I can do that. Separately, I'm able to fetch data like this:

```
$query = "SELECT starting_amount FROM comp ORDER BY item DESC LIMIT 3, 1";

$result = $conn->query($query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

and I'm able to update data like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE comp SET final_amount=25 WHERE item='Y'";
```

but I can't put the two together (I tried several ways and failed).  In other words, I am able to update a table record with data that I manually type, e.g. I type "25" manually in the update statement, which in this example is the data from 'staring_amount', but I don't know how to update with a statement that will automatically use data I fetch from the table. Again in other words, how do I write the update statement so that "SET final_amount=" is followed by fetched data? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

So, you just need to pass your fetched data into the query

```
$starting_amount = $row['starting_amount'];
$sql = "UPDATE comp SET final_amount=$starting_amount WHERE item='Y'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I highly recommend looking into prepared statements - using a prepared statement to insert data is an easy way to prevent SQL injection attacks and also will make what you want to do a little easier.

Here's an example of a prepared update statement using mysqli based on your example:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE comp SET final_amount=? WHERE item='Y'")
$statement->bind_param(25);
```

I'll assume for this answer that you want to use just the first row of the resultset.

Using your example above, you can replace the value in bind_param with a value from your row.

```
$statement->bind_param($row['starting_amount']);
```

Comment: thank you Eric! i'm going to look into prepared statements as i learn things... thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do them as separate statements, since you can join queries in an `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE comp AS c1
JOIN (SELECT starting_amount 
      FROM comp
      ORDER BY item DESC
      LIMIT 3, 1) AS c2
SET c1.final_amount = c2.starting_amount
WHERE c1.item = 'Y'
```

Comment: thanks Barmar. i'm still learning basic steps so at this time i'm confused about what c1 and c2 are. but hopefully as i learn i'll figure more things out! : )

Comment: They are table aliases. They allow you to use a short name to refer to longer table names, and they're needed when you need to refer to a subquery since it's not a named table.

Comment: They're also needed when you have multiple instances of the same table in a query, so you can distinguish them.